# How to update Firestore / documentation

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was checking the documentation about [updating a document in Firestore.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#kotlin+ktx_9:%7E:text=Update%20a-,document,-To%20update%20some)

This is the piece of code provided:

```
val washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC")

// Set the "isCapital" field of the city 'DC'
washingtonRef
    .update("capital", true) // <-- This one
    .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!") }
    .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e) }
```

Why even though we want to update `isCapital` do they mention it as `capital`? Is it a typo or something I have to consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a typo or something I have to consider?

No, it's not a typo. Cloud Firestore uses [Java Bean conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) for mapping fields between a Kotlin class and the fields of a document in the database.

This means that the `is` prefix on a field indicates that the field is of type boolean. So the fact that the `isCapital` field is mapped to a field with the name `capital`, it's indeed the expected behavior.

However, if you want to control the name of the fields that Firestore uses in the mapping process, then you can use the `PropertyName` annotation inside a Kotlin class:

```
@get:PropertyName("isCapital")
@set:PropertyName("isCapital")
@PropertyName("isCapital")
var capital: Boolean? = null,
```

Comment: So any time I have to update `isAnyValue` am I going to write it as `anyValue`?

Comment: If you are naming the field starting with `is`. Otherwise, you can simply name the fields in the document without `is`, to avoid the use of the annotations.